# How many pictures can I download from Flickr per day?

Tags: flickr

I need to download thousands of pictures for my thesis research and I was wondering if there is a Flickr download limit.

How many pictures can I download from Flickr per day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **no** download limit for Flickr. There is an [upload limit](http://www.flickr.com/help/limits/).

Answer (score 2):

There is no Flickr download limit. However, if you are using a tool to download Flickr images, it may be rate-limited because of [Flickr's API limits](http://developer.yahoo.com/flickr/).

Comment: That might just be through YQL... there is no mention a rate limit in the documentation on flickr.com, from what I've seen

Answer (score 2):

There are tools out there which will let you download photos on Flickr. And if you build your own tool, yes, there is no limit on the number of photos you can download. However, the maximum number of photos that any Flickr API call can return is 500.

I had a similar requirement and have built a tool to download photos from Flickr in Bulk. It's called Bulkr and can be used to download upto 500 photos in batches. And since you are going to be using it for research, I can give you a license key for free. Please contact me [here](http://clipyourphotos.com/feedback).

Check it out in the Flickr App Garden: [Bulkr](http://www.flickr.com/services/apps/72157622874451890/)